# Read all lines from TXT file and search only in every FIRST string of each line C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem displaying the result of my search in my listView. I have a TXT file and I only want to search for the first words of each line of the file. I don't know what condition should I put to do this...I was reading about FirstORDefault option but not working with my if statement. Below is my Text File and Display View Form.

I hope to hear from you....thanks. Please Help.

```
    private void btnSH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream history = File.Open("C:\\Users\\Sofia\\TestFolder2\\logfile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader hRead = new StreamReader(history);
        String viewHistory = hRead.ReadToEnd();
        String[] hArray = viewHistory.Split('\n');

        hRead.Close();
        history.Close();

        if (txtBoxSH2.Text != "")
        {
            string searchString = txtBoxSH2.Text;
            historyLstBox.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string line in hArray)
            {
                if (line.ToUpper().IndexOf(searchString.ToUpper())!= -1)
                {
                    historyLstBox.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have words separated by spaces, you could split the line by spaces and check the first element in the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to provide cleaner code:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetMatchingLines(string filename, string word)
{
    return File.ReadLines(filename)
               .Where(line => string.Equals(line.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(), 
                                            word,
                                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

then just add result of this method to `historyLstBox.Items`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use line.StartsWith(searchString) instead of line.IndexOf(searchString)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use `File.ReadLines` for this.

```
 string searchString = txtBoxSH2.Text;
 if (searchString == "")
      return;

 foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Sofia\\TestFolder2\\logfile.txt"))
 {
      if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(line))
           continue;

      if (line.Split(' ')[0].ToUpper() == searchString)
           historyLstBox.Items.Add(line);
 }
```